# Scan Double doesn't work with try-catch

Tags: java, try-catch, java.util.scanner

here's my code:

```
public static void setPriority(List<Performer> listperformer)
 {
  Scanner localsc = new Scanner(System.in);
  if(listperformer.isEmpty() == true)
  {
   System.out.println("- empty -");
   return;
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println("ID:");
   int id = localsc.nextInt();
   if(listperformer.size() < id || id < 0)
   {
    System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    return;
   }
   else
   {
    double priority = 1.0;
    try{
     System.out.println("Priority:");
     priority = localsc.nextDouble();
     listperformer.get(id).setPriority(priority);

    }catch(InputMismatchException e)
    {
     System.err.println("Invalid input!");
    }

   }
  }
```

When I want to scan something like 2,7 it works, but if i put instead of the comma a dot, it leads to the "Invalid input!" output.

Comment: Well first of all I had it without, this is only to try, why this code doesn't accept a dot

Comment: What is your Locale?  A comma and a dot do not mean the same thing in any locale.

Comment: ok, but normally a variable of type double always is with dot, or am I wrong?

Comment: In Java yes, because it was developed by Americans, but when reading input the Locale determines whether `,` or `.` is the decimal point so if `2,7` works most likely your locale is one where `,` is the decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you need to use US locale

```
Scanner localsc = new Scanner(System.in);
localsc.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: @FarazDurrani You should not be, but he should be

Comment: needed to wait 3 more minutes ;-) upvote doesn't work so far -.- will try it once again tomorrow!